# How to get the Style name of a paragraph in a libreoffice document with a python macro?

Tags: python, python-3.x, macros, libreoffice

I'm in need to create a python macro for some odt and ods documents.

I need to find the style name of a line and do some specific work for every style i found.

I can open the documents, get the line but not the style.
I've searched on internet and here but I found nothing.

Can someone help me with some piece of code?

N.B. I need a macro 'cause the list of odt files is in a calc workbook

Thanks

---

### EDIT  -- the solution is

thank to Jim K

```
oCursor = modelDoc.Text.createTextCursor()
    oCursor.gotoStart(False)
    sStyle = ''
    #loop for cursor
    while oCursor.gotoNextParagraph(False):
        sStyle = sStyle + oCursor.getPropertyValue("ParaStyleName") + '\n'
```

The code give the name of all style used in paragraphs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read the [ParaStyleName](https://www.openoffice.org/api/docs/common/ref/com/sun/star/style/ParagraphProperties.html#ParaStyleName):

```
style_name = cursor.getPropertyValue("ParaStyleName")
```

Comment: ok.It's not working for an "Unknown property: ParaStyleName" error

Maybe I understand why.
I have to create an invisible cursor and loop it line by line in the text.

Thanks for the help.